# What is the problem with this question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/502529/how-find-the-range-of-m) was asked almost 3 weeks ago and today it was closed. The first vote to close it is from the author of the question. It is strange, it seems that he edited the question and then voted to close. What is going on?

Comment: It's like someone else is messing with his account or something; none of the original asker's actions over the past few hours on that question make any sense.

Comment: Looks like someone desperately trying to make a question to away.   Possibly a contest or exam question of some sort?

Comment: If the OP doesn't have a good explanation for their actions, they should get a suspension for vandalizing Jack D'Aurizio's tour de force of an answer.

Comment: @MJD, he did not make any comment there until now.